# Android; button sound plays after default button sound

Tags: java, android, button, android-mediaplayer

In my application, I have put a button that plays its own sound by picking a random button sound source from the  `raw` directory.

But when the button is clicked, the default PHONE BUTTON SOUND plays first and then my custom button sound.

How can I disable the default phone button sound?

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    //will fetch a random button sound and load it in this variable.        
    ImageButton amazingPicsButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.amazingPics);
    amazingPicsButton.getBackground().setAlpha(2);
    amazingPicsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.jasfiddle.AmazingInterface.AMAZINGPICS"));

            //create random sound
            amazingPicsSound = createRandButSound();
            amazingPicsSound.start();
        }
    });         
}

private MediaPlayer createRandButSound(){
    return MediaPlayer.create(this, buttonSounds[r.nextInt(buttonSounds.length)]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all i think you should need to do is:

```
setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

However this may be global, you may need to make your own Button class and set this.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false).

Comment: where do i call this method in my code? I only want to disable the default phone button sound and keep my own application button sound running.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Button class and use that in the XML layout files...

```
package mypackagename.myApp

public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Then in thelayout files use the below XML for your buttons

```
<mypackagename.myApp.MyButton
    ...
</mypackagename.myApp.MyButton>
```

you can also try to put `android:soundEffectsEnabled=false` in a theme and then assign your theme to your activity